# OpenAM's WebAgent failing to install

Tags: forgerock

I am trying to setup Forge rock(OpenAM13.0) with OpenDJ 3.0,

deployed Open Am in tomcat and Installed opendj successfully.  setup where I end up with an error .

```
Environment:
- OpenAM(V 13.0).war with Tomcat (8.5.27)
- OpenDJ 3.0.0 for External Identity perupose.

-AS part of the process deployed the OpenAM war and on tomcat and could 
 able to login in with amadmin.

-Created policy set and policy and reqeust patterns as well.(followed
```

the forgerock getting started guide:https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/getting-started/).

-Here I installed apache 2.4  webserver could able to see the home page.

> Error:  when i try to configure the WEb agent I endup with below
>   error,could not able to proceed further.

But I could able to login from the openam login screen but end up with some session invalid exception in session.log and no session in access.csv log file.I could not able to understand and go further.help on this regard is greatly appreciated.

Attached the screen shot of different logs i got .

```
[WEbagent_insall_Log][1] - Log during web agent installation
[Session-Log][2] - Log at the server openam side 
[OpenaM_access.csv_log][3] log for open am side about the access
[WEbagent Installation][1] screen when I try to install webagent

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCFZ.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX1Tb.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQYUX.jpg
```

Please help on this.

Thanks
Venkat